# jQuery not define in bootstrap module

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use bootstrap for my website (with node.js). But I have the following error :

> /var/www/node_modules/bootstrap/js/transition.js:59
>   }(jQuery);
>     ^
>   ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
>       at Object. (/var/www/node_modules/bootstrap/js/transition.js:59:3)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
>       at require (module.js:380:17)
>       at Object. (/var/www/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/npm.js:2:1)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)

I tried to do a

```
var bootstrap = require('bootstrap');
```

in my main node.

I installed bootstrap with npm (`npm install bootstrap` from my folder). I also tried to instal jquery with the same way and to add a `var jQuery= require('jquery');` but it does not work. Do you have any idea what could be wrong ? I am starting node.js, i may miss something

Then I use `<link href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` in my HTML webpage to refer to bootstrap
`

Comment: Do you load jquery before bootstrap?

Comment: yes, I do a `var jQuery = require('jquery');var bootstrap = require('bootstrap');
`

Answer (score 75, accepted):

To use jquery plugins with npm/node you need to set the global jQuery variable before requiring your plugin [bootstrap in this case]:

```
global.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');
```

More details in this [npm blog](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/112064849860/using-jquery-plugins-with-npm) post

Comment: thanks! I love it that I don't have to shim this and shim that!

Comment: @Amjad Do you mean bootstrap specifically or some other jQuery plugin? What's the error you're getting? My initialization code with bootstrap 3.3.2 is: `var $ = require('jquery');
global.jQuery = $;
require('bootstrap');
require('malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin')($);`
and this works fine for me...

Comment: When I try this solution, I get the error "TypeError: Cannot set property 'emulateTransitionEnd' of undefined"

Comment: I get the same error "TypeError: Cannot set property 'emulateTransitionEnd' of undefined"

Comment: I have got the same error ... TypeError: Cannot set property 'emulateTransitionEnd' of undefined

Comment: Try changing `global.jQuery` to `global.jQuery = global.$ = require('jquery');` and see if that helps.

Comment: this works if I use a mix of JS and TS. What if I want a pure TS solution?